# Fake Facebook accounts

Tags: facebook-fql

We plan to make a new application. One person will be the first by voting in the competition. We want to prevent voting by opening false accounts.

- Can we get the opening day of a Facebook account?
- Are there any other ways of detecting false accounts?

Comment: This might assist you : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7332957/determine-when-user-created-facebook-account

Answer (score 1):

1. "Can we get the opening day of a Facebook account?"

   - First it's difficult because facebook doesn't expose that column of the user table with the public API.
   - Also if you try to loop back thry the is starting to limit how far back we can go in the stream, so you might not find the stream item Lix refers to.
2. "Are there any other ways of detecting false accounts?"

   - you can check the `verified` property of the user
   - you can set stipulations of a minimum number of friends
   - you can check to see if they have a profile picture setup other than default

Answer (score 0):

The date you opened the account now shows in the timeline.   What is needed is a profile pic taken from a scanned licence or something that can never be deleted and is available for verification. (having the system black out the info other than the foto)